# 2d Framework c++

Tags: c++, frameworks, 2d, cocos2d-x

I'm looking for a 2d framework with such things as  layers/particles/screen manager/sprite batch/parallax/etc coded in c++ out there? I'm looking for somethings that doesn't necessarily have graphics, because I want to add it on to airplay sdk. Or something I can easily rewire to do the graphics through airplay.

EDIT: I found what I needed: cocos2d was potted to c++ and airplay sdk (cocos2d-x). Thanks for the answers anyways!

Answer (score 4):

It may be a bit to hands on, you seem to be looking for more an engine, but you could definetly use http://www.libsdl.org/ for what you've requested (2D screen manager), also is quite an easy stepup to using sprites.

It may just be a bit more work than a simple plug and play or 'rewire'.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Cairo Graphics, it is 2D engine with multi layer support, and it can output to both screen and PDF.

Answer (score 3):

The best option is to use [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) libraries. [HERE](http://www.cs.clemson.edu/~malloy/courses/3dgames-2007/tutor/index.html) you can find an example using a 3D engine. The structure is applicable to a 2D game using cocos2d-x

Answer (score 2):

Can you describe what do you exactly want to do?
I guess you may find these helpful

[Wiki - Game engines](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Game_Engines)

[Wiki - another list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines)

Answer (score 0):

http://oxygine.org is exactly what you need. 
It is open source modern hardware accelerated 2D C++ framework for mobile and PC platforms. Features: OpenGLES 1/2, compressed textures, atlases, complex animations/tweens/sprites, scene graph, fonts, event handling, build tools, and others. Can be built on top of SDL2.0 or Marmalade SDK.